# IIS Attach to w3wp.exe Not Popping Up

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

This is an odd issue -- when I was working on my project last week, when I hit localhost, Visual Studio 2013 would pop up and warn me that `IIS/DefaultAppPool` was attempting to attach to my WCF service (w3wp.exe). That warning is not popping up any more and I am experiancing odd behaviour now with my program. I am wondering what causes this pop up to happen, and how can I get IIS to attach to this process again?

I'm not sure if it matters, but there was another pop up sometime last week that asked if I wanted to attach with another debugger, and I am thinking that may have thrown it off, I'm just not sure how to get back to IIS attaching to the process.

**EDIT**: w3wp.exe is *grayed out* when I attempt to go to Debug > Attach to Process, so I cannot attach to it that way.

Comment: Do you run visual studio as administrator?

Comment: did you change your "Attach To" settings...

Comment: @TMcKeown No, I am not even sure where those are located.

Comment: did you also register IIS as well as the .net framework you are using?

Comment: @FrankJohnson vs and pool should run under same user, or vs should be run as administrator, other way you won't be able to attach to process